# jQuery datatable deletes last index when saving column view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to keep the column state in an array with stateSaveCallback in jQuery datatable. By default, I have 13 columns and I only have 9 of them hide/show in my colvis button. My problem is that the array I keep is 13 true in the first place, after starting to hide, the length of the array decreases by 1 every time I hide it. however, the length of the array I want should remain constant 13, if the index is hidden, it should turn into false in that array, I've been trying for a long time, please help

I just tried colvis to rotate between the columns I added to the button, but it still showed the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is my `stateSaveCallback` function

```js
stateSaveCallback: function(settings, data) {
  var columns = [];
  $('#' + tableId + ' th').each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    columns.push(settings.aoColumns[index].bVisible ? true : false);
  });
  console.log(columns);
  var portfolioId = "@ViewBag.CurrentPortfolio.Id";

  var columnStatus = columns;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("DataTableVisibilityCustomization", "Portfolio")',
    data: {
      ColumnStatus: JSON.stringify(columnStatus),
      portfolioId: portfolioId
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result.data);
    }
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
stateSaveCallback: function (settings, data) {
var columns = element.columns().visible();

```
                var colVisState = $.map(columns, function (col, i) {
                    return col ? true : false;
                });

                data.colVisState = colVisState;
                var portfolioId = "@ViewBag.CurrentPortfolio.Id";

                var columnStatus = data.colVisState;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("DataTableVisibilityCustomization", "Portfolio")',
                    data: { ColumnStatus: JSON.stringify(columnStatus), portfolioId: portfolioId },
                    success: function (result) { console.log(result.data); }
                });
            },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).